# How do you address a person's assistant?

Tags: email

I wanted to contact a person **A**, whose website has the email of only his personal assistant (through which **A** asks to be contacted). I want to contact **A**, not the assistant. What is the format to write an email to the assistant, but actually addressing **A**?

Comment: This isn't a question about English, but about etiquette. In my experience, Indian practices in emails etc tend to be rather more formal than either British or American habits, so I'm not sure you're going to get answers that are useful to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it is written, it is a question about etiquette and e-mail formatting, not English.

Answer (score 1):

Please forward this email to A.

[Message]

When you tell someone to **forward** something, it means relay it to whoever it needs to be giving to.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Edited.